# How do I access a value from a form element which has a name attribute?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with a select field which has a *name* attribute.

```
$form['select_c'] = [
  "#type" => 'select',
  "#options" => [1,2,3],
  "#attributes" => ['name' => 'select_name'],
];
```

I am using that attribute to conditionally display some other form elements, but when I look at the content of `form_state->getValues()`, the *select_c* field is always empty.

However, when I comment out the `#attributes` line, I can see the right values for *select_c* with `$form_state->getValues()`.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: Conditional display of form elements is usually done with the #states in a form. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am using states as well for conditional display. Say when a user selects 1, Type 1 markup is displayed below, Case is similar for 2 and 3. Now when I try to view which value was selected in submit function with `form_state->getValues()` I can't see which value was selected

Comment: I recommend avoiding your approach altogether, of setting the #name attribute. The name attribute in Drupal form items is quite integral to the Form API, and messing with it has unintended consequences. If you re-write this question explaining what you are trying to do,the approach you have tried to take (so others are motivated to help), and the reason you took that approach, we can probably guide you to a more "Drupal-ly" suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Jaypan but I am following the instructions from official documentation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/conditional-form-fields

Comment: The example code on that page sets the ID, not the _name_ attribute.

Comment: But in first example code id is commented out and name is set 
``// 'id' => 'select-colour',
  'name' => 'field_select_colour',``

Comment: @kiamlaluno thank you so much. Changing it to id worked. First example in documentation for  $form['colour_select'] has the following code
```'#attributes' => [
        //define static name and id so we can easier select it
        // 'id' => 'select-colour',
        'name' => 'field_select_colour',
      ], ```
I followed that and made a mistake. Once again thank you so much.
Also @Jaypan thank you for pointing out that importance of #name attribute. I will avoid playing with it in future

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.